# convolving a multiset

Tags: combinatorics

You are given a list of terms 1,2,2,3,5,7,7,7,9 and see that there are 30,240 possible ordered arrangements.  Selfconvolve each of them: selfconvolving 1,2,2,3,5,7,7,7,9 has the result 141 and selfconvolving 2,5,7,3,9,7,1,7,2 has the result of 215.  How many other selfconvolved order arrangements have the result of 141 or 215?  Other than selfconvolving all 30,240 ordered arrangements, is there any way of determining this?

Comment: I for one have never heard the phrase "selfconvolve" and it doesn't appear in any texts on my shelf or in a cursory google search.  Could you please define the operation you are performing in greater detail?  In what way are you arriving at $141$ and $215$ from those arrangements?

Comment: The term 'selfconvolve' is used at OEIS, and it simply means to convolve a set of terms with itself. Thus selfconvolving 1,2,2,3,5,7,7,7,9 results in 1*9+2*7+2*7+3*7+5*5+7*3+7*2+7*2+9*1=141.